# Select all checkboxes - but only ones with the same table cell value

Tags: javascript

Hopefully I can explain this without overcomplicating the issue, so please bear with me. I already know how to write some JavaScript to select all check boxes within a form, but how would you go about doing the following?

Here is the code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="value1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        Some Field
    </td>
    <td>
        Bob
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="value2"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        Some Field
    </td>
    <td>
        Bob
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="value3"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        Some Field
    </td>
    <td>
        Fred
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="value4"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        Some Field
    </td>
    <td>
        Jack
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to be able to select/unselect all the checkboxes relevant to "Bob", but not Jack or Fred. The common data must be contained within a TD element. Is this even possible?

If someone could help that would be fantastic!

Many thanks for your reply subhaze but I'm not having much luck getting it to work, here is my code now:

```
function selectBOB() {
    var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for( var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++ ) {
        var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
        for( var k = 0; k < tds.length; k++ ) {
            if( tds[k].innerText == 'Bob' ) {
                trs[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked = 'checked'; 
            }  
        }
    }
}

<input type="checkbox" name="sAll" onclick="selectBOB(this)" /> Select Bob
```

Comment: Is this code being output by some kind of server side scripting language + database?

Comment: Yup - it is being generated by PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a super flexible solution since it relies on your markup to stay in that format but might get you headed in the right direction.

**[Live example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/Bnk77/)**

HTML

```
<input id="select" type="checkbox" data-name="Bob" onClick="setChecks(this)"  /><label>Select all Bobs </label><br />
<input id="select" type="checkbox" data-name="Fred" onclick="setChecks(this)" /><label>Select all Freds </label><br /><br />
<table id="myTable" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="value1" />
            </td>
            <td>Some Field</td>
            <td>Bob</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="value2" />
            </td>
            <td>Some Field</td>
            <td>Bob</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="value3" />
            </td>
            <td>Some Field</td>
            <td>Fred</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="value4" />
            </td>
            <td>Some Field</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
function setChecks( checkboxElem ) {
    var trs = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for( var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++ ) {
        var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
        for( var k = 0; k < tds.length; k++ ) {
            if( tds[k].innerText == checkboxElem.getAttribute('data-name') 
                || tds[k].textContent == checkboxElem.getAttribute('data-name')) {

                trs[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked = checkboxElem.checked;
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, and also you had the function name `selectBob()` but had the onclick set to `selectNR(this)`. I'll also going to update my answer with buttons to select and deselect.

Comment: Not to sound ungrateful - but your example doesn't work in Firefox :o(

Comment: @David, you don't :P   seems you can't get innerText from table cells in Firefox, I've updated the example to get either innerText or textContent which works in Firefox

Comment: Just as something additional which might come in handy - how would I go about having multiple "document.getElementById('select').onclick = function(){setChecks( 'Bob', this )};" so I could have in one page: document.getElementById('select').onclick = function(){setChecks( 'Fred', this )}; and document.getElementById('select').onclick = function(){setChecks( 'Jack', this )}; also?

Comment: If you have control over the HTML you could set a data attribute to the checkboxes and just pass `this` to them `<input id="select" type="checkbox" value="select bob" data-name="Bob" onClick="setChecks(this)"  />`. Take a look at this updated example and see if it might fit your needs. http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/Bnk77/10/

Comment: :P thanks, glad I was able to help! Also, here is a link that will explain the `data-` attribute if you're curious about it. http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/